# What is the default revalidate caching time in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

What is the default caching time Next.js uses when the `revalidate` property is not explicitly defined?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#duration-1

Comment: Thanks, but I read them and didn't find an official figure. Only in the examples is 3600 mentioned

Comment: Actually read it: _"The Data Cache is persistent across incoming requests and deployments unless you revalidate or opt-out."_ so there is no default.

Answer (score 0):

The default is not revalidate
Is it like static page or api return same response overtime.

From nextjs doc:

false: (default) The default heuristic to cache any fetch requests that set their cache option to 'force-cache' or are discovered before a dynamic function is used. Semantically equivalent to revalidate: Infinity which effectively means the resource should be cached indefinitely.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).